# Is black light (UV) bad?

Tags: biology, sunlight

This question is based on the damage a solar eclipse can do to your eyes.

In a parallel universe, the only light that reaches the Earth is the *dark one* — small amount of visible light and substantial amount of ultraviolet, just like the mix that reaches area with solar eclipse on our Earth, but with the same total brightness as our sunlight. People have already adapted to it, being able to see the world through that light.

If such a person came to our Earth (or a similar world) how would he see the world (colors and perception of it)? Would he even be able to see anything at all without years of adaption to our sunlight, assuming he is well adapted to uv-rich light of his world?

And how would we see on his planet? What would we need to do to visit our worlds without ill effects? What these effects would be?

---

You know that in a solar eclipse you can't stare at the sun, even though you can't see it's brightness. That hidden ultraviolet radiation...
Anyways, I meant the dark light, as in that manner.
If lets say a person used to that light visits earth, what will happen ?
And if a person let's say from earth, gets hit by an attack imitating this 'dark light's but super intense, what would the effects be ?

Sorry I wasn't clear enough. Hope this clarifies the things a bit. Also it is because I couldn't express my self properly...
My mother language isn't English, so I improvised on the words ( dark light ), though I did mention I was talking about that kind of light in the beginning, so I'm not quite sure on how you got confused ' This question is based on the damage a solar eclipse can do to your eyes. ' but now that I'm looking at it again, I really messed up on how I conveyed my questions....

Also thanks for the answer, but it's not quite what I wanted...
Mistakes happen, we are humans after all ( talking about my self, since this is my fault )

Also if you could reopen the question, I would be forever grateful, and if it is off topic, suggest a place I could migrate this question. If parts of it are off topic, then I will edit this question again, leaving only the on topic stuff.

**Edit 2** :

Mistake, the answer was quite what I was looking for.
But more is better, and I'm also looking for what would happen if the opposite occured ( a person used to UV rays, coming in contact with sunlight, for prolonged periods of time, something, which the answer didn't include, but I don't think anyone would know anyways.
So basically I'm 80% covered :p

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the only light that exists is the dark one".

Comment: Yeah, this seems on topic. However this doesn't give any information of what darklight is. The only darklight I know is Eigengrau, which would mean that there is no contrast in the other dimension, meaning that they cannot see at all, which would mean that the creatures living there would not have eyes. Being able to see through darklight is literally impossible if this is what you are refering to.

Comment: I think this is in reference to the coronal light of the sun, that which remains visible during a total solar eclipse.  So 1) would eyes adapted to an alternative star which emits only the wavelengths in the coronal light of our sun be of any use on Earth, and 2) what if you made a device that just blasted humans with simulated coronal light, would it hurt them, in what ways, and for how long?  I'm reluctant to edit the question without confirmation from the author I'm interpreting this correctly.

Comment: I agree - seems on topic but unclear. Light is, well, light. Define your "dark light", please. And define "bad". Of course if this dark light is a part of existing 3rd party world you are trying to understand, and not the one you are building, then this is off topic. But again, can't tell now, not enough data.

Comment: And anyways, it does have the makings of a worldbuilding question — once this “dark light” is properly defined, of course.  Too speculative for biology; too superficial for physics.

Comment: This question looks fine for WorldBuilding, though it looks like you are asking two questions. Normally you should ask one question at a time and use the input on that question to incorporate it into follow-up questions. Do you have any references you are using for the dark light? A wikipedia link or something similar that you can summarize and where we can look up the topic would be incredibly helpful in providing clarification.

Comment: Since "dark light" isn't a thing that actually exists, you can define it to have whatever properties you want, which means that the answers to your questions are pretty much whatever you want them to be, unless you want to clearly define what this "dark light" is, and then we can help you work out the ramifications of that definition.

Comment: If you meant "black light" as an ultraviolet, then please, edit your question and replace dark/black light words with **UV** or **ultraviolet** word. This will make it clear that you meant a light with certain frequency.

Comment: Guys edit freely, I suck at this.

Comment: @MariosZaglas It's not necessary to apologise so much. Making mistakes is normal, especially in a language you are not familiar with and on WorldBuilding.SE. We are different from a lot of other forums and SEs after all. Your edit provides a good clarification

Comment: It's not the light from the corona during a total solar eclipse that does damage to your eyes, it's looking at the sun in the moments before and after totality.  The light from the corona &c is just ordinary light: it's just not very bright compared to the output of the solar disk, so it gets washed out.  Just as you can't see the stars, and often not the moon, during the day.

Comment: I took liberty to "edit freely" as you suggested. Part after horizontal line is left unchanged and could be left out in my opinion. Part above the line is, I think, a decent question now. Of course don't hesitate to roll back or edit again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a translation error.

If by *dark light* you mean ultraviolet, we usually refer to it in English as *black light*.

If that is the case: our Sun gives off ultraviolet as part of its spectrum.  The effects are well known:

- It would cause sunburns
- It is damaging to the eyes in high concentrations
- It is very good at sterilizing stuff. Most microbes don't like it very much.

Some of the insects see in the ultraviolet spectrum. If you take a photo of some flowers in ultraviolet, you can see patters that are there to guide the insects to the pollen areas.

Someone who saw via ultraviolet would be able to see pretty well in our sunlight. Indoors, florescent lights would work but be pretty dim since, though they produce ultraviolet, the coating on them is designed to absorb it and **fluoresce** into white light (hence the name). Incandescent bulbs would be pretty useless though.

Comment: Yea I am talking about the ultraviolet light... forgot what you had written, and edited despite that. XD also you answered a part of the question, but I doubt anyone would know the opposite ( a person used to black light, exposed in sunlight )

Comment: I don't know what portion of sunlight is in the UV spectrum.  He'd be able to see but the sunlight might look a little dim to him.  The spectrum that we can see is less energetic than UV.  So, I doubt that it would have any effect on him (unless you include some mystical effect).  The most he would notice is that the sunlight would be warmer than he would expect from the dimness.  He might have some components in his skin that may be damaged since different molecules absorb different wavelengths of light.  Red paint on outdoor signs fades faster than most other colors.